# emacs yasnippets for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, yasnippet

I'm using emacs 24.3.1 for rails development and currently I end up with enh-ruby-mode when in my rails model files. I would like to use yasnippets for rails commands eg: typing 'bt' + tab expands to belongs_to.

Should my rails templates be put into my enh-ruby-mode snippets directory?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the repository for the snippets has enh-ruby-mode as a symlink to ruby-mode. Check your yasnippets snippets directory to see if that symlink exists. If not, either update your yasnippets or add the link yourself.

https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/blob/32bbd36d9a774b9cab6207523ffb5b24179b6505/enh-ruby-mode

Comment: I do have a link from enh-ruby-mode to ruby-mode, but what I'm asking is should I be putting Rails specific snippets into that directory as well?